# Word: Arrows in tabel cells

Tags: microsoft-word

I have the following example table:

[image: Example Table]

I want to introduce arrows to the cells (an example below. But also possibly something like from just right of the GG to the end of the first cell in each line etc.). I want the arrows (I added them by Insert -> Forms) to be exactly in the middle of the row of the cell(s) and I want to be able to move them around freely.

However, what happens to me is that there is a little blue anchor appears in some cells (possible even in other cells then the arrow is placed). This gives me many restrictions. Sometimes, the arrow "jumps" if I want to move it just a tiny bit. Sometimes, I use the "arrow keys" on the keyboard to move the arrows to the right, but they also go down at the same time ...

Also, the results in the document look different than the one in the print preview (arrows move down in the preview)

Is there a better way to deal with arrows in Tables in Word?

I am using the newest Word Version of Office 365

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that arrows are treated as connectors and are meant to be used on a separate canvas (which needs to be inserted/overlayed).  Connectors lock on to particular points (anchors) on an object and are meant to shift when the objects move.  They are also meant to be "intelligent" and change shape dynamically to minimize length of some such - this never works correctly in my experience and is the cause of these problems.

I'm looking for a way of drawing arrows sensibly on tables too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 and I was having a very similar problem.

I found that if you right-click the arrow (or any other shape in the table cell) and click on "more layout options", in the window that opens under the "position" tab, there's a tick mark by "Layout in table cell".

I unchecked that and pressed OK, and now shapes move as expected with the arrow keys.

Although, for some reason, after doing the above and restarting Word, the shapes move as expected, even when I don't untick the "layout in table cell" option.